# Can we learn anything from our "Greatest Hits" to date?

Tags: discussion

[Here's a list of the so-called "greatest hits" on academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits)

These are, roughly speaking, the questions that have got [the most positive attention from non-StackExchangers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/).

So, these the most accessible and useful questions. Or the most populist and lowest-common-denominator. Or, most likely, a mix of both.

What can we learn from them?

(other than there's a **lot** of discouraged graduate students out there, and [they did find the answers helpful](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/most-helpful?filter=all))